# IE makes you login again if you use a FQDN

Tags: internet-explorer, fqdn

So we are having a very wierd problem.  We just upgraded to IE 7 last week (god, how i wish that was a joke) and now certain links on our intranet sites will ask the user to login again.

It seems that any link that uses a fully qualified domain name to access a server will require the user to relogin.  If the link does not include the `.domainname.com` in the server name, everything works as it should.

After searching, I found that I need to add the domain to my intranet sites in IE to resolve this issue, but it is already there on all the machines that are having this issue.

Can any help?!

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i found the problem.  Its caused when the server in question is listed as a trusted site.

Under local intranet sites, we already had *.ourDomain.com.  So when any specific server got added to the trusted sites that was part of our domain, the error would occur.

So make sure you have you only have your domian listed, no specific server names!

Answer (score 0):

Evidently there's some interference with the session mechanism (cookies right?). You can try having a look at the cookies set on IE before and after the second login, if there's any difference it might give valuable insight into what's going on.

Comment: There are session cookies, but no, we aren't not using them to verify login.  Its expecting a domain login again (as if i were acessing from the outside world)